# Nginx: How to deploy front end & backend apps on same machine with same domain but different ports?

Tags: nginx, deployment, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two apps one for frontend built using ReactJS and one is for backend built using FastAPI. I have server machine where I have deployed both the apps. Now I want to use Nginx (because of SSL) to host both my application on the same machine with same domain name but the ports are different. I know how to do it for different domains or subdomain but I don't have another domain/subdomain with me right now. So I want to aks how I can achive this in Nginx?
For example my FE is using port 5000 & BE is using 8000,I am able to configure Nginx to serve my FE but I am getting this error,

> Blocked loading mixed active content

because my FE which is `https`trying to connect to backend on port 8000 which is not `https`.

Here is my nginx config file,

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate    /opt/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /opt/ssl/custom.key;


    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    server_name something-c11.main0.auto.qa.use1.mydomain.net;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    access_log /opt/MY_FE/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /opt/MY_FE/nginx-error.log;
    

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

 
}

server {
    if ($host = something-c11.main0.auto.qa.use1.mydomain.nett) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;


    server_name something-c11.main0.auto.qa.use1.mydomain.net;
    return 404;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated....